# OpenFileDialog causes "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread"

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following code in my C# WinForms application:

```
private void AddFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFile.RestoreDirectory = false;
    openFile.Filter = "PCAP files (*.pcap)|*.pcap";
    openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
    openFile.Multiselect = true;
    openFile.FilterIndex = lastUsedFileType;

    if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        lastUsedFileType = openFile.FilterIndex;
        foreach (string file in openFile.FileNames)
        {
            inputListBox.Items.Add(file);
            inputListBox.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When it calls the function ShowDialog, i get the following exception:

> First-chance exception at 0x00007fff77f48b9c in DataVerifierGUI.exe:
>   0x8001010E: The application called an interface that was marshalled
>   for a different thread.
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

The call stack doesn't exactly help either as it seems to be coming from the combase.dll.

Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
The full Form1.cs code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DataVerifierLib;

namespace DataVerifierGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        PCAPParserWrapper pcapParserWrapper = new PCAPParserWrapper();
        public static List<string> pcapSelectionList;
        public static int lastUsedFileType;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String someString = inputListBox.Items[0].ToString();
            for (int i = 1; i < inputListBox.Items.Count; i++ )
            {
                someString = someString + ",";
                someString = someString + inputListBox.Items[i];
                //pcapSelectionList.Add(item);
            }
            pcapParserWrapper.ParseWrapper(someString);
        }

        private void AddFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            openFile.RestoreDirectory = false;
            openFile.Filter = "PCAP files (*.pcap)|*.pcap";
            openFile.RestoreDirectory = true;
            openFile.Multiselect = true;
            openFile.FilterIndex = lastUsedFileType;

            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                lastUsedFileType = openFile.FilterIndex;
                foreach (string file in openFile.FileNames)
                {
                    inputListBox.Items.Add(file);
                    inputListBox.HorizontalScrollbar = true;
                }
            }
        }

        private void RemoveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputListBox.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                if (inputListBox.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    inputListBox.Items.RemoveAt(inputListBox.SelectedIndex);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Select a file to remove");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There are no items to remove");
            }
        }

        private void ClearFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (inputListBox.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                inputListBox.Items.Clear();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("There are no items to clear");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using multiple threads in your application?

Comment: Not as far as i'm aware. The C# GUI is communicating with a C++/CLI wrapper (which then talks to the underlying c++ unmanaged code). I also posted the full contents of the code.

Comment: My crystal ball says that the Main() entrypoint of your program is missing the *required* [STAThread] attribute.

Comment: If you comment out `PCAPParserWrapper pcapParserWrapper = new PCAPParserWrapper();` and the line that refers to it, does it still crash when you open the dialog?

Comment: I was debugging some issue with boost filesystem path (because it doesn't seem to work when the original call is from the C# GUI to the C++/CLI....). So I was changing the code to not use boost, and i'd left the "Enable Native code debugging" ticked on the C# app properties. I unticked it and it's fine now... seriously don't know why I ran into this problem or why that would cause the issue...

Comment: Could anyone tell me why "enable native code debugger" would cause this crash? I was purely using it to debug my unmanaged c++, but it seems like it was causing the C# GUI calls to screw up.

Comment: PS @HansPassant your crystal ball would be wrong ;)

Comment: Well then just don't fret about it.  You are not just debugging your own code, you also see exceptions thrown in the shell extension handlers that get loaded when you use OpenFileDialog.  You got a crappy one installed, it just won't work.

Comment: I also realised that you can't use filesystem-path or regex (boost functions) otherwise you'll get heap corruption. This is with C++/CLI and C# :(